# MongoDb schema optimisation with hierarchical array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello,
I'd like your advice on how to structure a mongoDb schema. Let's imagine I have a list of hierarchical jobs :

```
WebDevelopment :
    - php
    - html
    ....
MobileDevelopment : 
    - Kotlin
    - Java
    ....
... (and so on)
```

Let's say that a user can choose several technologies: php, kotlin ... , below is a simple Schema i have imagined:

```
// USER SCHEMA
const UserSchema:Schema = new Schema({
    jobs:[{
        type:String,
        ref: "job",
    }]
})
// JOB SCHEMA
const JobSchema:Schema = new Schema({
    jobs:{ type: String }
})
```

But how can i structure parent/childs of job? when querying mongoDb i want to find all user who uses php and/or kotlin with structured data child/parent. Is this possible ?

if I've explained it badly, please let me know.

PS : i use nodejs and mongoose as ODM

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your technologies like php, html, java as Tags. Then your tags have a type i.e. Web Development and Mobile Development.

Now, things are simple.

```
// USER SCHEMA
const UserSchema:Schema = new Schema({
    jobs:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Job",
    }]
})
    // JOB SCHEMA
    const JobSchema:Schema = new Schema({
        tags:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Tag" }]
    })
    // TAG SCHEMA
    const TagSchema:Schema = new Schema({
        name:{ type: String },
        ofType: {type: String }
    })
```

Comment: "ofType" can store values like "Web Development", "Mobile Development" etc. If you have a broader need for the category, then you can also create a Category Schema instead of using "ofType" and add tags to the category schema, depending upon the relationship you want to set in your data this can be expanded. I would suggest you look up for database relationships, like one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many.